# How to search for a negate a relationship in cypher

Tags: java, cypher

Im trying to find a relationship wherein, one of the entities does not map onto a specific value, I'm trying to use the WHERE NOT EXISTS statement but to no avail.

I've tried to find a relationship where a matches to b. But I also don't a to match to b when b has an attribute value of "test"

```
MATCH  (a)-[hasAttribute]->(b:Attribute)
WHERE NOT EXISTS a.code = "test"
return *
LIMIT 10
```

I need to find a relationship where a matches to b, and b does not have a value of "test"

Answer (score 1):

this is what you want:

```
MATCH  (a)-[hasAttribute]->(b:Attribute)
WHERE  a.code != "test"
return *
LIMIT 10
```